# Adding back in ActiveRecord to Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I started a rails app using the -O (--skip-activerecord) configuration, but now I want to add it back.

I added `require "rails/all"` to my `application.rb` file, and added in a `database.yml` file. Unfortunately, it's not picking up the database when I initialize the application.

I hacked together a module which will connect to the database if I call it, but there has to be a better, more railsy way. A rails app created without the -O option doesn't need any additional code to make the connection.

What else do I need to do to get rails to automatically connect to the database without explicitly making a connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that ActiveRecord 4 doesn't actually make the db connection until you call something. So just adding back in `require "rails/all"` and adding a database.yml does work. Just don't test it in the console without calling a method like `Model.last`.

Here's the rails issue explaining the functionality: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12804#issuecomment-29885300

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your `config/application.rb`. If you already have it commented, uncomment it.

```
require "active_record/railtie"
```

Add `database.yml` and restart the server